# Assess if HttpServletRequest is a valid method call

Tags: java, validation, servlets

I think it would be useful to validate if an http request will be valid when using the details in the request to invoke a method.

I do not know of any apache library that has a method that I can use to do this but if there is one please let me know as it will make things a lot easier.

This is the code I have so far but it is really bad and also incomplete. I have left comments inside the code with which parts need to be completed but if something can be improved, please show me how.

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Test extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            System.out.println("has correct parameters: " + hasCorrectParameters(request));
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /*
     * This method will check if an HttpServletRequest has the correct parameters required to invoke a method
     * ------------------------------------------------
     * Potential problems and how they get resolved
     * ------------------------------------------------
     * 1. Too many parameters for any of the methods in the specified class
     * SOLUTION: throw new ExcessiveParametersException().
     * 2. Too few parameters for any of the methods in the specified class
     * SOLUTION: throw new InsufficientParametersException().
     * 3. Inappropriate method being called based on details provided
     * SOLUTION: throw new IncorrectDetailsException().
     * 4. No way of determining what will be returned and what's expected to be returned
     * SOLUTION: ??
     * 5. No way of determining which of the parameters in the request should be associated with which of the parameters in the method signature
     * SOLUTION: ??
     * 6. Parameters of the wrong type being passed to the method
     * SOLUTION: Try and use instanceof to determine what the type of the parameter is. If it's not correct then throw new IncorrectDetailsException().
     */
    public Boolean hasCorrectParameters(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        //Class information
        int methodWithMostParamsInSignature = 2;
        int methodWithLeastParamsInSignature = 0;

        //Request information
        int paramsInRequest = 0;

        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String param = (String) parameterNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println(param);
            paramsInRequest++;
        }

        /*
         * 1. Too many parameters for any of the methods in the specified class
         * SOLUTION: throw new ExcessiveParametersException().
         */
        if (paramsInRequest > methodWithMostParamsInSignature) {
            throw new Exception("Excessive Parameters");
        }

        /*
         * 2. Too few parameters for any of the methods in the specified class
         * SOLUTION: throw new InsufficientParametersException().
         */
        if (paramsInRequest < methodWithLeastParamsInSignature) {
            throw new Exception("Insufficient Parameters");
        }

        /*
         * 3. Inappropriate method being called based on details provided
         * SOLUTION: throw new IncorrectDetailsException().
         */
        if (request.getParameter("method") != null) {
            if (request.getParameter("method").equalsIgnoreCase("isWalking")) {
                if (paramsInRequest == 1) {
                    isWalking(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("speed")));
                }
                if (paramsInRequest == 2) {
                    if (request.getParameter("lastLocation") != null) {
                        isWalking(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("speed")), request.getParameter("lastLocation"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * 4. No way of determining what will be returned and what's expected to be returned
         * SOLUTION: Not sure how to resolve
         */
        /*
         * 5. No way of determining which of the parameters in the request should be associated with which of the parameters in the method signature
         * SOLUTION: Not sure how to resolve
         */
        /*
         * 6. Parameters of the wrong type being passed to the method
         * SOLUTION: Try and use instanceof to determine what the type of the parameter is. If it's not correct then throw new IncorrectDetailsException().
         */
        //Parameters are always a String so I'm not sure how to check if it's a valid variable for the method signature
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean isWalking(Integer speed) {
        return speed == 2;
    }

    public Boolean isRunning(Integer speed) {
        return speed == 5;
    }

    public String isWalking(Integer speed, String lastLocation) {
        if ((speed == 2) && (lastLocation.equalsIgnoreCase("nearby"))) {
            return "Yup, you're walking";
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use reflection to call the methods that you want to call. This will give a runtime exception when the wrong amount of parameters is provided.

Definition:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
try {
  method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
  // ...
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  // ...
}
```

Then to invoke:

```
try {
  method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2,...);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
```

Api of Method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Comment: Thank you for this. However, how would you `method.invoke` based on an HttpServletRequest instance? The order of the params and the types can easily be confused surely?

Comment: for example `public String getAge(String person, String id)` might be mistaken for `public void getAge(String person, String id)` or `public String getAge(Person person, Integer id)`

Comment: The parameters have a name both in the http request as in the java method. Unfortunately you can't set or get parameter names at runtime (well you can in java 8 but requires extra build parameters and I'm not sure how that works efficiency whise) in java so you will need to build in some knowledge in your app for which methods you want to call. Or you can just set a precondition that the order of parameters need to be correct in the request. You can also use method.getParameterTypes(); and method.getReturnType() to identify the minimum though.

Comment: 1. You can't define two methods with the same signature (return type does not belong to the signature). 2. You define the signature of your method in the getMethod method: Name of the method + types of the parameters.

Comment: How would I create a method that can place the correct parameters in the call from the request though? i.e. `String m = request.getParameter("method"); java.lang.reflect.Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod(m, request.getParameter("??"));`

Comment: Test.getClass().getMethod(request.getParameter("method", request.getParameter("speed"));

Comment: This is very different to my initial method `hasCorrectParameters` though as this has to be customized for every method in the application.

Comment: You can get the parameter list as well and use them in sequence. Check the HttpServletRequest api for that. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Just trying some things for fun or are you working towards an application that needs to do something for real? Validation mostly depends on functional factors and thus can not be handled at the level you are aiming for. What if a parameter is missing? Maybe it is allowed to be null for some method, maybe it is not but should contain a string with 5 characters exactly ... There is no such library because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The idea behind it is to convert the request into a more java-friendly method call, so the same rules that apply in java will apply to the request. For a null being passed you will get a nullpointerexception. If it has to be 5 characters exactly then the method will implement that logic. I know that you can get a parameter list from the HttpServletRequest object but the problem still remains on how you will *use* those parameters to interface with java methods. I believe that my method `hasCorrectParameters` is on the right path but needs some work.

Comment: I think there is not much use for the thing you are trying to build. You can never know in advance that the type, order, amount, ... of parameters is correct. From http everything is also a string. You don't know what to cast to. Maybe the method you need to call is a combination of that all. Suppose the method is createUser(User user) and the data you get is firstName, lastName. But first you should create a user with new User(firstName, lastName). How will you fix that? If I would fully understand what you want to create I would still see no need for it either.

Comment: Well, having a clever method that can tell me if a request is valid based on what services the application offers will save me from having to use a framework like struts or jsf.

Comment: Well you can easily think of an easy validation mechanisms. For example create each functionality in a seperate class and provide a validate(HttpRequest req) method in that class as well that checks if all parameters are available.